# Read and remove all messages in a MSMQ (via RemoveCurrent method)

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I try to read all messages from a MSMQ via the `GetMessageEnumerator2` method, but always obtain only 1 message, vs using the `GetAllMessages` method, where I obtain the correct number of messages...

Where is the "bug" in the following code :

```
//var messages = queue.GetAllMessages(); // HERE I HAVE 5 MESSAGES
var messages = queue.GetMessageEnumerator2();
ReadQueryMessages(messages, removeAfterRead: true);

//...

ReadQueryMessages(MessageEnumerator enumerator, bool removeAfterRead = true)
{
    List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
    // enumerator.Reset(); - didn't help
    while (enumerator.MoveNext(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)))
    {
        messages.Add(enumerator.Current);
        if (removeAfterRead)
            enumerator.RemoveCurrent();
    }
    // process messages - HERE I HAVE ONLY 1 FIRST MESSAGE
}
```

**PS** *(for "duplicate-moderators")*
My question does not ask **HOW**, but **WHY only one** when removing

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i get all the available messages on a MSMQ Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228684/how-can-i-get-all-the-available-messages-on-a-msmq-queue)

Comment: @MethodMan: My question does not ask **HOW**, but **WHY only one** when removing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the `RemoveCurrent` does not work (or works, but breaks the queue reading), but I fixed by adding the `queue` as parameter:

```
List<ELetter> ReadQueryMessages(MessageQueue queue, 
                                MessageEnumerator enumerator, 
                                bool removeAfterRead = true)
{
    List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)))
    {
        messages.Add(enumerator.Current);
        if (removeAfterRead)
            queue.ReceiveById(enumerator.Current.Id); 
            // enumerator.RemoveCurrent(); - this does not work properly!
    }
    // here I have 5 messages in the list - OK.
}
```

Comment: `RemoveCurrent` moves the enumerator to the next item in the queue, so you're effectively calling `MoveNext` _twice_ in that scenario.

Comment: Anway, why only one from 5 messages?